# Memory leak in .NETCF - creating dynamic controls?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiling

I have a problem with a memory leak in a .NET CF application.

Using [RPM](http://blogs.msdn.com/stevenpr/archive/2006/04/17/577636.aspx) I identified that dynamically creating controls are not garbage collected as expected.  Running the same piece of code in .NET Window Forms behave differently and disposes the control as I expected.

See the output from RPM via PerfMon for the ***Process Heap*** counter: 
[image]

GC Heap:
[image]

My best guess is that the Weak Reference to the Panel is for some unknown reason not making the object eligible for GC, can it be?

**Please note:** Even though **Dispose()** solves the problem for the sample, I can't easily incorporate it into the existing application as it is not as clear cut to determine when the object is no longer in use.

I have included a simplified version of the source to illustrate the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CFMemTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Calling this event handler multiple times causes the memory leak
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel uc = new Panel();
            // Calling uc.Dispose() cleans up the object 
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** 
1. Calling GC.Collect() also doesn't result in the panels being cleaned up. 
2. Using .NET CF 2.0 SP1 on a Windows CE 4.2 device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some additional information here that explains this behaviour.

[According to Ilya Tumanov](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=4002811&SiteID=1&mode=1):

> **Everything UI related on NETCF is
>   intentionally removed from GC scope so
>   it is never collected**. This behavior
>   is different from desktop and has been
>   changed in NETCF V3.5 (unless running
>   in compatibility mode).
>
> It is so different because managed UI
>   classes on NETCF are completely
>   different from desktop. They are thin
>   wrappers over native implementation
>   which was needed to achieve acceptable
>   performance.
>
> I’m not sure there’s such a resource.
>   But really, all you need to know is:
>   it’s never collected, must call
>   dispose. You actually should do that
>   on desktop as well but if you don’t
>   its way more forgiving. Not so on
>   NETCF.

Answer (score 2):

A Form does not automatically Dispose all Controls created in its code, as it has no way to know it exists.  To get the Form to Form to Dispose it automatically when it's Disposed, you need to add it to the Controls collection.

Now in your case that may not do anything.  I can't tell if your example is contrived, or real world.  If it's real-world, then the behavior is expected, as the Panel doesn't get collected when the variable goes out of scope (not sure it does on the desktop either).  It becomes available for collection, but that simply means that on the next collection pass it will be swept.  Unless you're causing a GC, then it's not going to be freed.

I'd highly recommend you take a look at the [MSDN webcast on memory management in the CF](http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/detail/webcastdetails.aspx?seriesid=86&webcastid=1032318791).  It provides a much more thorough explanation as to what's happening under the hood - far more than we could provide in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have a memory leak? The .NET Compact Framework garbage collector works slightly differently to the one in the full .NET framework. From [Steven Pratschner's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/stevenpr/archive/2004/07/26/197254.aspx):

> A collection is initiated when either:
>
> - 1MB of objects have been allocated,
> - An application is moved to the background,
> - A failure to allocate memory occurs
> - An application calls GC.Collect.

Comment: Hi Mitch, I read Steven's blog and can confirm that these objects are not freed, even after: Calling GC.Collect() or allocating more than 1MB of objects

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to dynamically remove the Button Click EventHandler too, as you can see from this blog : 
http://blogs.msdn.com/stevenpr/archive/2007/03/08/finding-managed-memory-leaks-using-the-net-cf-remote-performance-monitor.aspx

It is from Steven Pratschner too.

By the way, the webcast mentioned above is linked here:
http://msevents.microsoft.com/cui/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?culture=en-US&EventID=1032318791&CountryCode=US

Hope this helps!